# Query using left join

Tags: mysql

i have this query,

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users where id ="'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'"';
```

My problem is that i don't know how to left join it with another table..using another where or "On" clause..

can you please help me with the syntax of this?

It should be something like `SELECT $query FROM users,retailer ON $query.user_id=retailer.user_id`
....

```
"SELECT users.first_name, retailer.date
FROM users AS users
LEFT JOIN retailer AS retailer ON users.user_id=retailer.user_id
WHERE users.user_id=" . $_SESSION['user_id']
```

Thanks!

Comment: The question seems slightly incomplete. What fields are you trying to retrieve? What tables are you trying to retrieve data from?

Comment: The point is, i get the user_id from the first query, then i want to retrieve for example, all fields of the second table, retailer but on the condition that the first table user_id should be equal to retailer.user_id

Comment: That's what `ON users.user_id=retailer.user_id` does.

Comment: is there a chance that your query selects users where some of them are retailers but not all of them? Cause if so then LEFT JOIN makes sense. Otherwise simple WHERE is enough to connect users and retailer tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEFT JOIN is pretty simple

For your example:

```
$query = "SELECT u.*, r.*
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN retailer AS r ON u.user_id=r.user_id
WHERE u.user_id=" . $_SESSION['user_id']
```

"AS" keyword creates alias so there is no need of making alias "users" of table "users".

Secondly, LEFT JOIN is useful if there is a chance that second table contains no matches to first one yet you still need that attribute to show - attributes of second table will have NULL values if no matches found.

I'm not really sure you need a LEFT JOIN in your query.

Comment: Can you please see the updated code i'm putting? thanks.. so you can tell me how to rewrite it better... please!

Comment: I solved it :) i used another method, but your answer helped a lot, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.*, retailers.*  
FROM retailer 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON retailer.user_id=users.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is:

```
$query = "SELECT u.*, r.*
FROM users u, retailer r
WHERE u.user_id=" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "
AND u.user_id=r.user_id";
```

I've noticed that SO posters tend to use the explicit JOIN language, is it more standards-compliant or just a stylistic choice? I know it's necessary for LEFT OUTER JOIN, so is this just for consistency?